# Why is my LilyPond code not including barlines?

Tags: lilypond

I really do not understand why no barlines appear in my simple LilyPond code.

Here a part of my code:

```
  \version "2.22.1"

% this is my first score
\language "english"

\header {
   title = "Hallelujah"
   composer = "Leonard Cohen"
} %

\layout {
  indent = #0
  line-width = #190
  ragged-last = ##t
}
%%%%%%%%% Variables Declaration

pad = \override TextScript.padding = #4
vpad = \overrideProperty Score.NonMusicalPaperColumn.line-break-system-details
          #'((Y-offset . 40))

vpads = \overrideProperty Score.NonMusicalPaperColumn.line-break-system-details
          #'((Y-offset . 80))

% LilyBin
#(define-markup-command
  (woodwind-diagram-x layout props 
    instrument user-draw-commands)
  (symbol? list?)
  #:properties ((upper-hole-filled #f)
                (size 1)
                (thickness 0.1)
                (graphical #t))
  (let* ((ww-diagram
          (interpret-markup layout props
            (make-woodwind-diagram-markup
             instrument user-draw-commands)))
         (hole-circle
          (make-circle-stencil size thickness upper-hole-filled))
         (midline
          (make-line-stencil (* thickness 2) (* -0.80 size) 0 (* 0.80 size) 0))
         (upper-circle-and-midline
          (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge hole-circle Y DOWN midline (* 0.80 size))))
    (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge
     upper-circle-and-midline Y DOWN ww-diagram (* 0.80 size))
    ))



fdo = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five six))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}} 
fdodiez = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (one two three four five six1hTF))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}} 
 
fre = _ 
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}


fmi = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}

ffa = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}

fadiez = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF three four))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}

fsol = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (two five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}

fla = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}
fla_fo = _
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (two five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}
    

fsi = _ 
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #t)
    \override #'(size . 0.7)  {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}

fsib = _ 
    \markup {
    \center-column {
    \override #'(upper-hole-filled . #f)
    \override #'(size . 0.7)  {
    \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute  #'((cc . (two five))
                                 (lh . ())
                                 (rh . ())) }}}
 

\score {
    \relative c' {
    %\numericTimeSignature
    \pad
    \tempo 8=114
    \time 6/8
    \pad 
    {e8\fmi g4\fsol g8\fsol g4\fsol g8\fsol} 
    {a8\fla [a8\fre a8\fla] (a4\fla) e8\fmi }  
    {g8\fsol [g8\fsol g8\fsol] (g8\fsol) [g8\fsol g8\fsol]}
    {a4\fla a8\fla a4\fla g8\fsol}
    {a8\fla a4\fla (a8\fla) [a8\fla a8\fla]}
    {a4\fla g8\fsol g4\fsol f8\ffa}
    {g8\fsol g4\fsol (g4\fsol) r4 r4.}
    {e8\fmi g4\fsol g8\fsol g4\fsol g8\fsol} 
    {a4\fla a8\fla bf4\fsib g8\fsol}
    {c8\fdo [c8\fdo c8\fdo] (c4\fdo) a8\fla}
    {c8\fdo [c8\fdo d8\fre] (d4\fre) c8\fdo}
    {d8\fre [d8\fre d8\fre] (d4\fre) d8\fre }
    {e8\fmi (e8\fmi) [e8\fmi d8\fre] d4\fre}
    {c8\fdo (c4.\fdo) r4.} \undo \pad % using group \pad --start and stop for the group...
    }
}

\score {
    \relative c'' {
      \numericTimeSignature
    \pad
    \time 6/8
    \pad 
    {e,4\fmi g8\fsol}
    {a4.\fla a4.\fla (a4.\fla) a4\fla g8\fsol}
    {e4.\fmi e4.\fmi (e4.\fmi) e4\fla g8\fsol}
    {a4.\fla a4.\fla (a4.\fla) a4\fla g8\fsol}
    {e4.\fmi (e8\fmi) [f8\ffa e8\fmi]}
    {d4.\fre (d4.\fre) c8\fdo c2.\fdo r4. r4}
    {e8\fmi g4\fsol g8\fsol g4\fsol g8\fsol} 
    {a8\fla [a8\fre a8\fla] (a4\fla) e8\fmi }  
    {g8\fsol [g8\fsol g8\fsol] (g8\fsol) [g8\fsol g8\fsol]}
    {a4\fla a8\fla a4\fla g8\fsol}
    {a8\fla a4\fla (a8\fla) [a8\fla a8\fla]} \undo \pad % using group \pad --start and stop for the group...
    }
}
     \layout {
     %ragged-right = ##t
    % #(layout-set-staff-size 20)
      \context {
      \Score
      \omit TimeSignature
      \omit BarLine
      \override SpacingSpanner.base-shortest-duration = #(ly:make-moment 1/32)

     }         
        }
```

[image: output of LilyPond code]

Comment: `\omit BarLine`?

Comment: Not only is the obvious candidate (\omit BarLine) not accounted for, but the code isn't runnable. If you want help debugging a piece of code, a runnable example must be provided.

Comment: Hi Aaron, adding a hole code":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `\omit BarLines` instruction from the end of your code and the bar lines will be included. This was confirmed using [LilyBin](http://lilybin.com/); the output is below. (Note: The Version statement must be excluded to run in LilyBin.)

[image: LilyPond output]

Comment: Great, Thank you. But somehow the third bar(third measure) fall inside pitches, how to fix it?

Comment: @Tommy_tsa The problem is that the very first note should be beat 6 of a pickup measure ("anacrusis") rather than beat 1 of the first measure. Add `\partial 8` before the first note.